Roughing out shower niche
I am presently roughing in a shower niche (20" wide prefer 24") for a curbless shower (45x60), and after demoing the wall it appears the builder placed studs 24 o.c., which is fine as I will need to add some additional studs to meet Schulter's Kerdi board requirement for 1/2" board w/ 16" o.c. spacing.
Okay, no biggie.  My issue is that right smack dab in the middle where the niche was supposed to go the builder placed a 2x4 for blocking on the adjacent bathroom's tub surround.  I thought about notching out the surround blocking for the spacing for the niche, but also don't want to compromise the tub surround's attachment.  Image below:

*** Note: I do plan on taking out the tub/surround in the future, but can't do it now as that is the only running shower left in my household. ***
I am reaching out to y'all to see if anyone has any ideas.
Thanks in advance!

Two smaller niches or one multi-shelf niche might be a solution.

How soon do you plan on taking out the adjoining tub surround? And how tolerant are you of funky? I’m thinking that you might be able to pull out the blocking with little or no ill effect, and then if the surround seams do separate a bit you could seal with silicone and/or tape.

@JonCuster Thanks for the reply.  I have thought about this as well, but I am somewhat a stickler for symmetry, and if I go with the smaller niche(s) then they would be off center and look wonky.

@dlu It will most likely be next year as I need to finish this bathroom up before fall (plenty of time), and am getting married in the fall.  Regarding my tolerance of funkiness, I am pretty tolerant (albeit if it's temporary)....however, I'm not certain what my county inspector would think about the funkiness.

Might be worth seeing if the inspector would come out and look at it with you. Some are really helpful and seem to appreciate being approached as resources.

Is the wall in question load-bearing?
